# padding in vector with zeros

Tags: c++, vector, padding

my plaintext is first converted to binary text, then it should be divided into 64 bit blocks and the key has to encrypted tese blocks separately. for example, if my text has 90 bits it should be supplemented with zeros so that it has 128 bits. I do not know how to do this. here is my code:

```
string ifile = "filetxt.txt";
string ofile = "file2.txt";
string key = "keywordd";
vector<int> k;
vector<int> txt;
char text;
vector<int> o;
int i;
int c = 0;
int d = 1;

void f() {
    ifstream ist ("filetxt.txt");
    ofstream ost ("file2.txt");
    int a[64], i;
    while (ist >> text) {
        for(char& text : key) {
            for(i=0; i < 8; i++){
                a[i] = text%2;
                text = text/2;
            }
            for(i=i-1; i >= 0 ;i--){
                k.push_back(a[i]);
            }
        }
        if (ist) {
            for(i=0; i < 8; i++){
                a[i] = text%2;
                text = text/2;
            }
            for(i=i-1 ;i >= 0 ;i--){
                txt.push_back(a[i]);
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if(k[j] == txt[j]) {
                    o.push_back(c);
                } else if (k[j] != txt[j]) {
                    o.push_back(d);
                }
            }
            for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
                ost << o[i];
            }
            for(i=0; i<8; i++) {
                cout << o[i];
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
        cout << k[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    for(i=0; i<64; i++) {
        cout << txt[i];
    }
}
int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

i was to do something like this:

```
if (txt.size()< 64){
    for(i= 0; i< 64- txt.size();i++){
        txt.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

i think that the problem is in the txt vector because if i want to print it i

Comment: Your example code is not what you want... it only increases the `txt` to 64 bits... You seem to want to align to 64-bit blocks... 
But it also seems that you are storing each bit in an `int`. That's quite inefficient.

Comment: do you know how can i fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy:

```
if (txt.size()< 64)
    txt.resize(64);
```

This will simply pad out the vector with the default value for `int`, which is 0.

If you want a value other than 0 (`c` as your code suggests) then it's:

```
if (txt.size()< 64)
    txt.resize(64, c);
```

Comment: that only fixes her code... which is incomplete. She asked for a multiple of 64.

Answer (score 3):

What you want is [`std::vector::resize`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize).  By default it will increase the size of the vector to the size requested (if the vector is less then said size), and any elements added will be value initialized, which for an `int` means zero initialized.  That gives you

```
if (txt.size() % 64 != 0)
    txt.resize(txt.size() + (64 - (txt.size() % 64)));
```

---

Also note that 64 `int`'s is **not** 64 bits.  An `int` has to have at least a size of 16 bits meaning 64 of them will be at least 512 bits.  If you actually need to have 64 bit chunks, you should be using a std::uint64_t for the bit chunks (or something like it)

Comment: here is my filetxt `alamakota` and heres my output `000010100000101000001010000010100000101000001010000010100000101000001010` and thats 72 characters and i want it to be 128. after printing the vector I see added zeros and do you know where may be an error in the encrypted outpatch.

Comment: @sonia I've update the if statement to increase the vector to the next multiple of 64.  That should do what you want.

Comment: IMHO your update seems incorrect. It should be something like `64*(txt.size()/64+1)`

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah, it was wrong.  I've updated it with a working version.

Comment: it doesnt make any difference. output is the same

Comment: @sonia Sorry, there was still a mistake.  Did you use `txt.resize(txt.size() + (64 - (txt.size() % 64)));` like I have it now?

Comment: it didnt make any difference

Comment: @sonia Weird.  It works here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d86d872d720778d

Comment: @NathanOliver when it's used in the whole code it doesn't work its probably because of the wrong size of the txt vector but we don't know why its happening

Answer (score 1):

Do something like the following as last step:

```
if ((txt.size() % 64) != 0){
    for(i= 0; i< 64-((txt.size() % 64)); i++){
        txt.push_back(c);
    }
}
```

This way, no matter which length your plaintext is, your `txt` vector will always end with a multiple of 64 length padded with zeros (`c`) if necessary.

Comment: @JHBonarius not to mention that it's underhanded contrived code... :-) I needed a while until I understood that the condition `i < (txt.size() % 64)` works correct. Ehem... just `txt.size() % 64` would have been done as well (and made the `if` obsolete as well as any counting of `i`).

Comment: Actually the I had to fix the loop in the following way: for(i= 0; i< 64-((txt.size() % 64)); i++) because we have to add only the part missing to reach 64 length.

Comment: @JHBonarius why do you thing this approach would have bad performance?

Comment: @Scheff I'm not getting your point, why the condition would be obsolete?

Comment: Have you noticed that whenever you push something to `txt` then the `txt.size()` increases by 1? Hence, `i` and `txt.size()` (and `txt.size() % 64`) are running with equal distance until `txt.size() % 64` is 0. Then, `i` is greater than `txt.size() % 64` and loop ends. That's the reason why it actually works. If you had used `n = txt.size() % 64` and `i < n` then it wouldn't because `n = 64 - txt.size() % 64` gives the correct number of fill elements.

Comment: Please, check your code (e.g. in [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/)). I bet, after the edit it doesn't work anymore.