# comparing vectors after padding

Tags: c++, vector, padding

hour ago i asked qeustion about padding. [padding in vector with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867330/padding-in-vector-with-zeros/60867456?noredirect=1#comment107692616_60867456) and
i ve made some changes

```
if (txt.size() % 64 != 0)
    txt.resize(txt.size() + (64 - (txt.size() % 64)));
```

and here is my filetxt alamakota and my output 000010100000101000001010000010100000101000001010000010100000101000001010 and thats 72 characters and i want it to be 128. after printing the vector I see added zeros and where may be an error in the encrypted output.
i think that txt vector has wrong size but i dont know why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [padding in vector with zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60867330/padding-in-vector-with-zeros)

Comment: i mean...  thats my question. i gave it above

Comment: Does your vector have the correct size?  How are you getting that output?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you put the relevant bits from your prior question in this question?

Comment: Actually, the exposed code appears correct to me. I couldn't reproduce your issue: [**Test on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4e3c157263edc81)